# Don't Update If There Is Data Earlier

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

I have form as below.

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+   Id     :  TextBox                            +
+   Name   :  TextBox                            +
+   Mob    :  TextBox                            +
+   Photo  :  File Option                        +
+                                                +
+   Submit   Update                              +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

What I want to do is update the data for the respective Id. For update I have query as below.

```
PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE myTable SET name=?, mob=?, photo=? WHERE id=?");
pst.setString(1, personName);
pst.setString(2, mobileNum);
pst.setBinaryStream(3, InputStreamData);
pst.setString(4, personId);
pst.executeUpdate();
```

**I have problem. I will explain with scenario.**

Suppose id is 1 and I already have data for personName & file. Now I enter mobile number only. . How could I avoid `pst.setBinaryStream(4, InputStreamData);` statement? I don't want to enter any data as data is already present. Is there any sql statement where I can insert data.

I can pre-populate only Name data BUT NOT file data.

### Edit 1

Solution for this is, have many UPDATE statements. BUT the problem is I have many fields. I can't use so many UPDATE statements.

### Edit 2

What I tried is read the photo data & set that data in setBinaryStream as below.

```
pst.setBinaryStream(4, rst.getBinaryStream(1));
```

But it give me ERROR as

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setBinaryStream(ILjava/io/InputStream;)V

javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setBinaryStream(ILjava/io/InputStream;)V
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1542)
```

--

```
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setBinaryStream(ILjava/io/InputStream;)V
at com.sac.databean.PersonalInformationDataBean.editPersonalInfo(PersonalInformationDataBean.java:1530)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invokeMethod(BeanELResolver.java:779)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:528)
at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:257)
```

Comment: Have you tried [`INSERT IGNORE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html)

Comment: @MahmoudGamal : I am using UPDATE statement... NOT insert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pst.setBinaryStream(4, rst.getBinaryStream(1), (int) rst.getString(1).length());` did the trick.

Comment: Maybe it does the trick but is inefficient and kind of ugly. You are sending the data (a lot of data) forth and back to the database.

Answer (score 2):

When a user edits his personal information using the form, the form should be pre-popuated with his current name and phone number.

This way, if he changes only his phone number, he won't touch to the name input field containing his name, and the form will be submitted with his current name and his new phone number. And you can update all the fields in database.

It's a UI problem, not a database problem.

Comment: I am populating data. But the problem is I have file option. I can't pre-populate data.

Comment: Use a dedicated form to update the photo alone, and another one to update all the other fields.

Comment: can you please take a look at updated question? I posted actual problem that I am facing....

Comment: well in actual form, I have many fields of type FILE... so thinking of one statement instead of many UPDATE statements...

Answer (score 0):

You can use two UPDATE statements. One for personal information, the other for file(s). The latter would be only executed when the user actually uploaded a new photo (it's easy to check when it's submitted via web form).

Alternatively you can have two UPDATE statements, one that only updates personal information, and another one that updates personal information AND file(s). As before, the latter would be executed when the user actually uploaded a new photo.

Comment: suppose I have 15 file option, then u want to say to have 16 update statement??

Comment: That's doable, if you have a numbered naming scheme of columns in the table (eg. FILE1, FILE2, and so on), you can create a parameterized method that will return UPDATE statement for a particular column. The same can be done if each column name is different (just pass the column name as parameter to method that generates the UPDATE statement). If that doesn't work either for some reason I rather would go for 16 differnt update statements instead of re-updating files in DB as you are trying to do. It's very inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

The error your getting as part of edit 2 is saying that method has not been implemented.

Try looking at [MySQL-BLOB-setBinaryStream](http://www.herongyang.com/JDBC/MySQL-BLOB-setBinaryStream.html)

Test 3 is passing in the length of the stream and this method seems to be implemented.

I am assuming your using the JDBC 3.0 which is used in those tests.